# Как заместить методом класса схему switch-in-switch?

Tags: java

Имеется задача(сборник задач по программированию Златопольский):

4.115.*В некоторых странах Дальнего Востока (Китае, Японии и др.) использовался
(и неофициально используется в настоящее время) календарь, отличающийся
от применяемого нами. Этот календарь представляет собой 60-летнюю циклическую систему.

Составить программу, которая по заданному номеру года нашей эры n печатает его название по описанному календарю в виде: "Крыса, Зеленый".

Мое решение:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TaskCh04N115 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Год: ");
        int year = str.nextInt();
        int year_east = (year % 60) - 4;
        int element = (year % 60) / 12;
        if (year_east < 0) {
            year_east += 12;
        }
        else if (year_east > 11) {
            year_east = year_east % 12;
            }
        switch (year_east) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("rat ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("bull ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("tiger ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("rabbit ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("dragon ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("snake ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("horse ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("sheep ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("monkey ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("cock ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println("dog ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println("pig ");
                switch (element) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("tree ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("fire ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("earth ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("metall ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("water ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Код неудобочитаем, поэтому:

Вопросы:

1. Как заместить внутренний switch-case методом какого-либо класса, либо как заместить методами класса обе switch-case конструкции?
2. Как вывести выводимые слова в ОДНУ строку, в формате "Крыса, Зеленый"? Сейчас это два слова в двух строках.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TaskCh04N115 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Год: ");
        int year = str.nextInt();
        int yearEast = (year % 60) - 4;
        int element = (year % 60) / 12;
        if (yearEast < 0) yearEast += 12;
        else if (yearEast > 11) yearEast = yearEast % 12;

        System.out.println(getYearName(yearEast) + " " + getColor(element));

    }

    private static String getColor(int element) {
        switch (element) {
            case 0: return "tree";
            case 1: return "fire";
            case 2: return "earth";
            case 3: return "metall";
            case 4: return "water ";
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported operation for 'element' " + element);
    }

    private static String getYearName(int yearEast) {        
        switch (yearEast) {
            case 0: return "Rat";
            case 1: return "Bull";
            case 2: return "Tiger";
            case 3: return "Rabbit";
            case 4: return "Dragon";
            case 5: return "Snake";
            case 6: return "Horse";
            case 7: return "Sheep";
            case 8: return "Monkey";
            case 9: return "Cock";
            case 10: return "Dog";
            case 11: return "Pig";
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported operation for 'yearEast' " + yearEast);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Почему бы не составить 2 мапы, из которых доставать по соответствию числовых ключей нужные значения?
2. Можно первое значение выводить не с println, а просто с print, тогда не будет второе значение выводиться с новой строки. Или можно конкатенировать 2 строки, или воспользоваться форматтером. Вариантов - масса!